# Internationalization and Validation

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, internationalization

My app has a registration page for new users and I'm trying to carefully support as many languages and locales as possible.  One of the rules for their desired username is that it must be alphanumeric, but when I type Japanese characters into that field it never passes validation.  Do you know of any good resources on best-practices for this type of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you doing your validation? +[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] includes Japanese letter characters.

Comment: It actually turned out to be a problem with how I was sending the text to my server to ensure the name wasn't already taken.  I wasn't encoding the request as UTF-8.